# In R, how come I can find mean of a population but cannot find simple random sample without replacement?

Tags: r

This is what I got.

```
po = c(900,822,781,805,670,1238,573,634,578,487,442,451,459,464,400,366,364,317,328,302,288,291,253,291,308,272,284,255,270,214,195,260,209,183,163,253,232,260,201,147,292,164,143,169,139,170,150,143,113,115,123,154,140,119,130,127,100,107,114,111,163,116,122,134)
mean(po)
[1] 305.75

srs_without_replacement = po(1:10,3,replace=FALSE)
```

> Error in po(1:10, 3, replace = FALSE) : could not find function "po"

What can I do to make it "find" function "po"? I'm sorry if the title looks quite like nonsense but I really don't know how to describe it.

Comment: Are you looking for random sample from `po`? if yes then try this `sample(po[1:10],3,replace = FALSE)`

Comment: The object `po` you defined is not a function - it is a vector, try `str(po)` to see the structure of you object `po`

Comment: `sample(po, size=3, replace=F)` is probably what you're after

Comment: sample() works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The function `sample` takes a `vector`, the `size` of your draw and `replace`, if you want or not replacement after each draw.

```
po = c(900,822,781,805,670,1238,573,634,578,487,442,451,459,464,400,366,364,317)

sample(po, size=3, replace=F)
```